# Equivalent definitions of Poincare inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I can't seem to find this anywhere but I can find that there are (at least) two definitions of the Poincare inequality. One is
$$
 \int_\Omega |f|^2 dx \leq c\int_\Omega |\nabla f(x)|^2 dx
$$
for $f \in H_0^1(\Omega)$, and the other is
$$ 
 \int_\Omega |f - \bar{f}|^2 dx \leq c\int_\Omega |\nabla f(x)|^2 dx 
$$
where $\bar{f} = \int_\Omega f dx$ and $f \in H^1(\Omega)$. Here $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ is say a nice bounded domain.

Should I be thinking of these as different (but called the same)? Or are they equivalent in some way that I can't see? For instance I would imagine that to prove the first implies the second I would say something like if $f \in H^1 \setminus H_0^1$ then if I subtract the mean $\bar{f}$ then $f - \bar{f} \in H_0^1$ but this just doesn't seem true. But then the fact they are called the same thing would seem to suggest that the two are equivalent or perhaps that one implies the other? Even if they are not, is there any relationship between the two?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, it's been edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second inequality can be written as
$$
\|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \le c \|\nabla f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \quad \forall f\in H^1(\Omega): \ \int_\Omega f =0.
$$

They are two different kind of similar inequalities: these allow to control the $L^2$-norm of the function by the $L^2$-norm of its gradient.
Of course, constant functions do not satisfy such an inequality. So this case has to be ruled out either by the choice of a subspace of $H^1(\Omega)$ or
by using $f-\bar f$ in the estimate on the left-hand side.

Comment: Now that you've written it in this form, would I be right to suspect that there is no relationship (e.g. one way implication or equivalence) between the two types of Poincare inequality and that I should think of "a" Poincare inequality as any type of inequality of the form $||f||^2_2 \leq c||\nabla f||_2^2$ for $f$ belonging to an appropriate space (be it $H_0^1$ or $\{f \in H^1 \mid \int_\Omega f = 0\}$)?

Comment: I would say yes. I am not aware of a proof to derive one inequality from the other, but who knows.

Comment: Thanks - your answer helped me understand what is considered a Poincare inequality. I guess I can't really see why one space is dense in the other so I'll just accept that I shouldn't expect different types of Poincare inequalities to be equivalent.